# Reading Result from HTTP Request in Android

Tags: php, android, get, urlconnection, http-request

I need to read the response message retrieved after connecting to an online PHP script. This script returns the following:

```
{"success":1,"innerResult":[{"username":"raafat","password":"123"}]}
```

I just need to read the success value from this message. I tried HTTP Request:

```
    private class GetPersonDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        //Activity act;
        Context mContext;

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        /*
        public void onPreExecute() {

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
*/

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread

            // Check for success tag

            try {
                success = 3;
                List<NameValuePair> paramss = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                success = 4;
                paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",n.getText().toString()));
                paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",p.getText().toString()));
                success = 5;
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("akmiengineering.com/insurance-app/search_username.php", "GET", paramss);
                success = 6;

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt("success");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success is" + success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (success == 1) {
                    //   onPostExecute();
.......





        } else {

.......
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
```

The code stops here:

```
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("akmiengineering.com/insurance-app/search_username.php", "GET", paramss);
```

and the success value is 5. I couldn't detect what's causing the problem, so I tried using URL Connection instead:

```
   URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://akmiengineering.com/insurance-app/search_username.php?username=adla&password=123");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                System.out.print(current);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //If you want further info on failure...
            }
```

But also my code is stopping here:

```
    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

I don't know what is it that I'm doing wrong. Please help me.

UPDATE:

This is the logcat:

```
07-09 14:03:58.221    9554-9610/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
07-09 14:03:58.321    9554-9610/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ Motion event has invalid pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16.
07-09 14:03:58.321     598-1749/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ found out /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
07-09 14:03:58.381     598-1749/? W/audio_hw_primary﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 102539 to 46439
07-09 14:03:58.451     598-1749/? W/audio_hw_primary﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 65759 to 46439
07-09 14:04:03.831   9750-10534/com.bluestacks.bstfolder D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 711K, 25% free 2688K/3576K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
07-09 14:04:09.951    9783-9911/com.bluestacks.gamepophome D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.5.3﹕ NetworkManager->handleMessag: msg:{ when=-40ms what=1001 target=android.os.Handler }
07-09 14:04:18.291     591-1700/? D/MDnsDS﹕ MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll timed out
07-09 14:04:18.291     591-1700/? D/MDnsDS﹕ Going to poll with pollCount 1
07-09 14:04:19.581  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication.MainActivity.yalaconnect(MainActivity.java:187)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-09 14:04:19.591  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18433)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 14:04:19.601  12243-12243/com.example.adla.insurancemobileapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 1275 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-09 14:04:58.951   9750-10534/com.bluestacks.bstfolder D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 729K, 25% free 2687K/3576K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
```

Comment: It seems as if you cannot connect from the device. Do you get an exception? Do you have [permissions to access the internet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET)?

Comment: There is no exception and I do have permissions set in the manifest file.

Comment: You need to read the result in the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`- which I don't see you have created in your post. Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309781/httpurlconnection-unable-to-connect-to-url-in-android/31311135#31311135) may help you to understand `AsyncTask` a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new project just to test your code for url connection, because I tested your code and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The URL seems ok. You might need to set an HTTP proxy to connect. If you are debugging on a device and everything else works, this is strange. If you are using an emulator, try to change the settings following the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1570627):

- Configuring wireless settings on the emulator after starting it up
- Set the `--http-proxy` parameter when starting the emulator ([ref, see section *Network*](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html))
- Configure the proxy in the HTTP client: I don't think them `makeHttpRequest` method supports that, but you can use `java.net.Proxy` with your `HttpURLConnection` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433296/)

Answer (score 0):

In your first approach, I think the problem is that you make a Http Request without having some sort of Http Client.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321799/android-http-get) and yes, I know the API is deprecated. You should have a HttpClient and a HttpResponse. In my opinion, the deprecated way is easier to understand when you're new in this matter.